# INCORRECT_APP_CREDENTIALS here maps android

Tags: android, here-api, heremaps-android-sdk

So i've followed the tutorials to implement HERE maps on my android application.
Added the credentials in AndroidManifest, the dependencies im app/build.gradle and yet i get this error = **INCORRECT_APP_CREDENTIALS**
Any hints?
thx

Comment: This means there is a typo in your credentials, or you took the wrong credentials. Or your credentials are no longer valid. Or you pasted into the wrong place. Either way, you can try to verify if you have set the exact credentials as shown on your HERE account page.

Comment: Did you add the downloaded credentials.properties file in .here directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the credentials being correctly added to your AndroidManifest.xml file, you also need to ensure that the application package name matches exactly (both in the manifest and the application gradle file).

build.gradle (app):

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "PACKAGE NAME"
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              package="PACKAGE NAME">
...
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid"
        android:value="APP ID" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken"
        android:value="APP CODE" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.here.android.maps.license.key"
        android:value="LICENSE KEY" />
```

[image: Here SDK Credentials]

Comment: yeah, I managed to fix it. It was mainly an enviroment issue. Thanks for the reply!